# SQLite query combining two result sets that use AND

Tags: sql, sqlite

Here's my simple query:

```
Select user_id, body 
from Messages where (Messages.author = 'john' and Messages.receipt = 'erick' 
UNION ALL (Messages.author = 'erick' and Messages.receipt = 'john');
```

---

I'm just trying to combine these two simple select queries and getting something like:

```
user_id  body
------------------
1        hello 
2        hi john
2        hello this is erick
1        this is john!
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
Select user_id, body 
from Messages where (author = 'john' and receipt = 'erick') or
(author = 'erick' and receipt = 'john')
```

By the way, since you are selecting data from only one table, you don't have to specify its name every time you'll refer to a field.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing your where condition:

```
Select body
from Messages 
    where 
(messages.author = 'john' and messages.receipt = 'erick') 
or 
(messages.author = 'erick' and messages.receipt = 'john')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use previous answers. I think they are better performance.

My answer is just to clarify `UNION` keyword: `UNION` joins two rowsets and should be used as following:

```
-- One rowset:
SELECT user_id, body FROM Messages WHERE author = 'john' AND receipt = 'erick'
UNION ALL
- Another rowset:
SELECT user_id, body FROM Messages WHERE author = 'erick' AND receipt = 'john'
; -- Union of both is returned!
```

However, if you are looking for a rows in a single table avoid `UNION`: just write a according `WHERE` condition.